# Scripts not working after TFS 2015 to 2018 upgrade

Tags: tfs

I am trying to make a full upgrade ftom TFS 2015 to TFS 2018.
In my TFS 2015 I had some customizations which run some scripts.
Some of them I managed to make them work but I am stuck with some which don't work.

I think it's because in my TFS 2018 I am missing some dlls:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.WindowsForms.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.OfficeIntegration.Common.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.OfficeIntegration.Common.tlb
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.OfficeIntegration.Excel.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.OfficeIntegration.PowerPoint.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.OfficeIntegration.Project.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ProjectManagement.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Sync.Mapping.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Sync.Project.Server.Library.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Sync.ProjectServerApi.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Sync.Shared.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Controls.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Controls.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.ControlsCore.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.dll
Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll
```

My scripts are running with Powershell. In TFS 2015 everything was working ok but now If I try to run them with the TFS 2015 dlls I get a lot of errors. Like this:

```
Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: Credential.
at Get-RestApiCredentials,
C:\Program Files\TFSPowerShell\Modules\Ecom.TFS\Ecom.TFS.Utils.psm1: line 21 at Get-SonarEndpointId, 
C:\Program Files\TFSPowerShell\Modules\Globo.TFSSetup\Globo.TFSSetup.psm1: line 23 at New-GloboBuildDefinition, 
C:\Program Files\TFSPowerShell\Modules\Globo.TFSSetup\Globo.Builds.psm1: line 93 at Provision-Release, 
C:\Program Files\TFSPowerShell\Modules\Globo.TFSSetup\Globo.Releases.psm1: line 99
```

or this:

```
TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required. - Microsoft Team Foundation Server body,button 
 { font-family: 
 { background: transparent; border: 0; color: #106ebe; cursor: pointer; } function toggle(event) { if (!event.key || event.key === " " 
 || event.key === "Spacebar" || event.key === "Enter") { var icon = document.getElementById("moreInfoIcon"); var section = document.getElementById("moreInfo"); 
 var wasShowing = section.style.display === ""; icon.src = wasShowing ? "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8%2F9hAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC%2
 FxhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAAOwgAADsIBFShKgAAAABl0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAUGFpbnQuTkVUIHYzLjUuODc7gF0AAAB2SURBVDhPY2AYBThDoKWlJa2jo0OO7CBaunTpfxAGGmRCliEgzc%2BePfs%2Ff%2F78%2F01NTZokGwI
 yAARAhkybNo10Q2AGwAwBeuV%2Fa2urHtEuWb58OWUuABkAC4Pm5mY7om2GKQQZAMJkaQYZAgx5P4rSAclOHjANAOQrXesb81M5AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" : "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABA
 AAAAQCAYAAAAf8%2F9hAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC%2FxhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAAOwgAADsIBFShKgAAAABl0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAUGFpbnQuTkVUIHYzLjUuODc7gF0AAABCSURBVDhPY2AYBfQJATU1NWsgLifLNhUVFVeg5v8gTLIBM
 M2RkZGkG4CsmWQD0DWTbAAowGD%2BRqLJC0SSA24EagAAq9sjtZrUZogAAAAASUVORK5CYII%3D"; section.style.display = wasShowing ? "none" : ""; event.target.setAttribute("aria-expanded",
 String(!wasShowing)); } } Error The page you are looking for is currently unavailable. TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required. 
 More information about this error TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required. Things you can try: 
 Refresh the current page Go back to the previous 
 page Sign in as a different user Submit feedback to Microsoft about this error Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. 
at Get-SonarEndpointId,
 C:\Program Files\TFSPowerShell\Modules\Globo.TFSSetup\Globo.TFSSetup.psm1: line 26 at New-GloboBuildDefinition,
 C:\Program Files\TFSPowerShell\Modules\Globo.TFSSetup\Globo.Builds.psm1: line 93 at Provision-Release,
 C:\Program Files\TFSPowerShell\Modules\Globo.TFSSetup\Globo.Releases.psm1: line 99
```

But note that this same scripts were working fine in TFS 2015.
So I tried to change the dlls used by this scripts. After that I get no errors but they are not working as they should.

So I am trying to get the missing dlls but my TFS 2018 doesn't have them. How can I get them?

Comment: Can you share the script...?

Comment: Is there a way to share it in private?

Comment: just censor sensitive information